# Erro ao atualizar toda a tabela JAVA

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, query, sql-update

Estou tetando executar um update em massa para atualizar todos os preços dos produtos cadastros no sistema, somando o valor passado pelo usuário ao preço unitário do produto cadastrado, de acordo com a empresa logada no sistema e a categoria do produto. Estou recebendo o seguinte erro.

Objeto Produto:

```
@NotNull(message = "é Obrigatório!")
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "categoria_id", nullable = false)    
private Categoria categoria;

//Campo criado para identificar a quem pertence os dados gravados no DB
@NotNull(message = "é Obrigatório!")
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "empresa_id")    
private Empresa empresa_id;
```

Objeto Categoria relacionado com Objeto Produto;

```
@Entity

@Table(name = "categoria")
public class Categoria implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue 
    private Long id;

    @NotEmpty(message = "é Obrigatório!")
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 60)  
    private String descricao;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "categoria_pai_id")  
    private Categoria categoriaPai;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "categoriaPai", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)    
    private List<Categoria> subcategorias = new ArrayList<>();

Método UPDATE:

    //Alterar todos os preços dos produtos somando VALOR REAL ao valor cadastrado por CATEGORIA
    @Transactional
    public void alterarPrecosValorRealPorCategoria(ProdutoFiltro filtro){            
        try {
            Query query = manager.createQuery("UPDATE Produto p SET p.valorUnitario = "
                + "(valorUnitario + :valorReal) WHERE p.empresa_id = :empresaLogada and "
                + "p.categoria.categoriaPai = :categoriaSelecionada");
                    query.setParameter("valorReal", filtro.getPrecoReal());
                    query.setParameter("empresaLogada", filtro.getEmpresaLogada());
                    query.setParameter("categoriaSelecionada", filtro.getCategoria());

                    query.executeUpdate();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Valores empresaLogada, alorReal e categoriaSelecionada, são passadas da view através do produtoFiltro. Estou a dias tentando resolver!

Conforme orientação do amigo @Caffé que tem tentado me ajudar nesta questão segue mais detalhe do problema.

Query gerado pelo Hibernate:

Query:

```
Hibernate: update produto cross join  set valor_unitario=valor_unitario+? where empresa_id=? and categoria_pai_id=?
```

> Não consegui entender porque ele gera esse "cross join"

Erro completo gerado:

Erro:

```
2016-02-18 13:51:18,701 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000
2016-02-18 13:51:18,701 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'set valor_unitario=valor_unitario+19 where empresa_id=2 and categoria_pai_id=16' at line 1
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1692)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1700)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractQueryImpl.executeUpdate(AbstractQueryImpl.java:70)
    at br.com.networkst.exatocomercial.repositorio.Produtos.alterarPrecosValorRealPorCategoria(Produtos.java:199)
    at br.com.networkst.exatocomercial.repositorio.Produtos$Proxy$_$$_WeldSubclass.alterarPrecosValorRealPorCategoria(Produtos$Proxy$_$$_WeldSubclass.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.SimpleInterceptionChain.invokeNextInterceptor(SimpleInterceptionChain.java:85)
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.InterceptorInvocationContext.proceed(InterceptorInvocationContext.java:127)
    at br.com.networkst.exatocomercial.util.jpa.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.SimpleMethodInvocation.invoke(SimpleMethodInvocation.java:30)
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.SimpleInterceptionChain.invokeNextInterceptor(SimpleInterceptionChain.java:69)
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.InterceptorMethodHandler.executeInterception(InterceptorMethodHandler.java:112)
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.InterceptorMethodHandler.invoke(InterceptorMethodHandler.java:88)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler.invoke(CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler.java:55)
    at br.com.networkst.exatocomercial.repositorio.Produtos$Proxy$_$$_WeldSubclass.alterarPrecosValorRealPorCategoria(Produtos$Proxy$_$$_WeldSubclass.java)
    at br.com.networkst.exatocomercial.controle.CadastroProdutoBean.alterarPrecosTodosProdutos(CadastroProdutoBean.java:278)
    at br.com.networkst.exatocomercial.controle.CadastroProdutoBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.alterarPrecosTodosProdutos(CadastroProdutoBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:278)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:274)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:39)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.exec.BasicExecutor.doExecute(BasicExecutor.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.exec.BasicExecutor.execute(BasicExecutor.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.executeUpdate(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:429)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(HQLQueryPlan.java:364)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.executeUpdate(SessionImpl.java:1290)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.executeUpdate(QueryImpl.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.internalExecuteUpdate(QueryImpl.java:358)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractQueryImpl.executeUpdate(AbstractQueryImpl.java:61)
    ... 89 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'set valor_unitario=valor_unitario+19 where empresa_id=2 and categoria_pai_id=16' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:939)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3878)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3814)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2478)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2625)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2551)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2073)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2009)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5094)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1994)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:204)
    ... 97 more
Fev 18, 2016 1:51:18 PM com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase execute
ADVERTÊNCIA: #{cadastroProdutoBean.alterarPrecosTodosProdutos}: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly
javax.faces.FacesException: #{cadastroProdutoBean.alterarPrecosTodosProdutos}: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
```

> Solução do problema: OBS: Leia os comentários para entendo o porque da alteração de createQuery para SQLQuery:

```
    @Transactional
public void alterarPrecosValorRealPorCategoria(ProdutoFiltro filtro){
    try {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

        SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery("UPDATE produto p JOIN categoria c ON"
            + " p.categoria_id = c.id SET p.valor_unitario = (valor_unitario + :valorReal)"
            + " WHERE p.empresa_id = :empresaLogada AND c.categoria_pai_id = :categoriaSelecionada");

                query.setParameter("valorReal", filtro.getPrecoReal());
                query.setParameter("empresaLogada", filtro.getEmpresaLogada().getId());
                query.setParameter("categoriaSelecionada", filtro.getCategoria().getId());

                int quantidadeProdutosPrecosAtualizados = query.executeUpdate();

                FacesUtil.addInfoMessage("Total de " + quantidadeProdutosPrecosAtualizados
                    + " dados afetados!");

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Configure o log para "debug" a fim de mostrar o comando SQL completo gerado ou, mais simples, nas configurações (propriedades do entity manager factory ou no persistence.xml) sete a propriedade *hibernate.show_sql* para *true*. De posse da query completa, teste ela à parte do programa (usando uma IDE do MySql, por exemplo) e veja se coleta mais pistas. Você também pode atualizar a pergunta colando aqui  a query.

Comment: Obrigado, farei estes teste e posto para mais detalhes, gostaria de informar também que pesquisei muio esse erro, e mesmo com as dicas de mudar o drive do MySQL não resolvei.

Comment: Uma dúvida: por que você não utiliza o Hibernate para fazer esse update? Ex.: `session.saveOrUpdate(objetoMapeado);`

Comment: @Rodrigo Porque ele está "tetando executar um update em massa", que é diferente de obter cada entidade, atualizar em memória e depois persistir. Para um grande volume de dados, o custo de resgatar-atualizar-persistir pode ser inviável.

Comment: @Rodrigo, o motivo é justamente o citado pelo amigo Caffé, minha preocupação é com desempenho em grandes volumes.

Comment: Bom @Caffé, com sua dica descobri que o erro de syntax é causado pelo trecho  + "p.categoria.categoriaPai = :categoriaSelecionada"); do da minha query, pois p.categoria é um atributo dentro de produto, porém o categoriaPai é um atributo dentro do meu Objeto Categoria. Só que não sei como resolver. Desculpa se eu não tiver conseguido explicar de forma clara. Caso não entenda tento dar mais detalhes.

Comment: @CDaniel Será que *p.categoria.categoriaPai* é do tipo *Categoria* enquanto o parâmetro *categoriaSelecionada* passado é um tipo Java (um long indicando um Id, por exemplo)? Seria bom atualizar a pergunta com a query gerada e os detalhes de como você chegou a esta conclusão até agora. Pode ser útil também mostrar mais da declaração e relacionamento entre as entidades.

Comment: @Caffé, Quanto ao valor passado em categoriaLogada já me certifiquei que o mesmo e do tipo Categoria mesmo. Vou atualizar a pergunta como recomendado.

Comment: O SQL gerado pelo Hibernate está errado e aparentemente ele não conseguirá gerar este comando corretamente porque ele não permite JOIN no update (a navegação *p.categoria.categoriaPai* causa um join): http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.2/manual/en-US/html_single/#batch-direct. A documentação recomenda usar subquery para estes casos, e na subquery você pode usar JOIN se precisar. Se você não conseguir fazer com subquery por mais alguma outra limitação (do Hibernate ou do MySql) a opção é usar NativeQuery neste update.

Comment: @Caffé, muito obrigado por me ajudar tanto, realmente você estava correto, aprendi muito estudando para resolver este erro. Usei SQLQuery criando uma nova SQL e funcional perfeito.

Comment: @CDaniel Legal, fico feliz que tenha dado certo.

Comment: Não esqueça de documentar a resposta e fechar a pergunta...

Answer (score 1):

Olá - Não entendi se voce realmente resolveu ou teve que mudar a abordagem. Mas no seu código tem um visivel erro na atualizaçao da tabela.

```
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery("UPDATE produto p JOIN categoria c ON"
            + " p.categoria_id = c.id SET p.valor_unitario = (valor_unitario + :valorReal)"
            + " WHERE p.empresa_id = :empresaLogada AND c.categoria_pai_id = :categoriaSelecionada");

                query.setParameter("valorReal", filtro.getPrecoReal());
                query.setParameter("empresaLogada", filtro.getEmpresaLogada().getId());
                query.setParameter("categoriaSelecionada", filtro.getCategoria().getId());
```

Veja que em: p.valor_unitario = (valor_unitario + :valorReal) voce nao setar um novo valor e sim um texto e pelos logs sua aplicaçao reclama justamente disso. veja o que ele gera:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'set valor_unitario=valor_unitario+19

Ou seja, se voce quer atualizar o valor voce tem que fazer valor_unitario=:novoValor e passar exatamente o que valor que voce quer no query.setParameter. Uma opcao seria resgatar o valor antigo e somar com o gerado pela aplicação. Setando unicamente um valor na sua query.

Dica: sempre olhe os logs gerado do sql para ver que consulta voce esta tentando aplicar, e faca ela diretamente no seu banco

Answer (score 1):

Oi. Acho que encontrei o problema. Está na sua query. Faça da seguinte forma:

```
 @Transactional
    public void alterarPrecosValorRealPorCategoria(ProdutoFiltro filtro){            
        try {
            Query query = manager.createQuery("UPDATE Produto p SET p.valorUnitario = "
                + "(p.valorUnitario + :valorReal) WHERE p.empresa_id = :empresaLogada and "
                + "p.categoria.categoriaPai = :categoriaSelecionada");
                    query.setParameter("valorReal", filtro.getPrecoReal());
                    query.setParameter("empresaLogada", filtro.getEmpresaLogada());
                    query.setParameter("categoriaSelecionada", filtro.getCategoria());

                    query.executeUpdate();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Se Notar, antes você tinha: 
SET p.valorUnitario = " + "(valorUnitario + :valorReal)
O Hibernate estava tentando tratar a palavra **valorUnitario** como comando sql ao invés de atributo da classe Produto.